# How to remove bookmarks from webbrowser app in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

Whenever accessing the Activities" and/or bookmarks tab Ubuntu Touch takes ages (10+ seconds) to respond. I read somewhere that too many bookmarks may slow the performance. Not that I have that many bookmarks, but I would like to try and remove the ones I have. I have tried press-and-hold on the bookmarks, but no delete action is triggered. How do I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the bookmarked page and once it has loaded, tap the bookmark star symbol to the right of the URL.